# Strange error with assertThat and Hamcrest is() and nullValue()

Tags: junit, hamcrest

I have a method I was converting from standard `assertNull` and `assertNotNull` to use `assertThat`.

I started changing a few of the assertions from:

```
assertNull(asyncResultsContainer.getQueryOutagesFuture());
```

To this:

```
    assertThat(callSession.getOutages(), is(nullValue()));
```

But when I have `nullValue()` inside `is()` I start getting inconsistent assertion failures that seem to span different test methods and it is hard for me to deduce the pattern of this failure except for:

When I convert the `nullValue()` alone like:

```
assertThat(callSession.getOutages(), nullValue());
```

The issue goes away.

So can someone explain why using `nullValue()`

```
static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> nullValue()
```

as a parameter to `is()`

```
static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> is(org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)
```

should not work?

Comment: AFAIK it *should* work fine inside `is()`. Can you create a small example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am trying to get one, but the error seems random but might be related to the `akka` thread registry that is involved in this test.

Comment: The `is()` method is syntatic sugar and doesn't add much.  I, also, have found that it causes problems, so I leave it out, using `equalTo()` when I mean that.